# How to replace white space with semi-colon in text file using Python?

Tags: python, whitespace

I have a large text file that contains many separated values. But the text file has values that are separated by white space and semi-colons. Below is what some lines look like in Unix with the Less command:

```
#CHROM  POS     ID      REF     ALT     QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT
chr7    149601  MERGED_DEL_2_39754      T       .       141.35  .   AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=37;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=<DEL>;AF1000g=0.09
chr7    149616  rs190051229     C       .       108.65  .       AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=35;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.00
chr7    149628  rs3814456       A       .       129.31  .       AC=0;AF=0.00;AN=2;DP=37;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;1000gALT=G;AF1000g=0.14
chr7    149634  rs146001818     G       T       1375.63 .       AC=2;AF=1.00;AN=2;BaseQRankSum=0.456;DP=39;Dels=0.00;FS=0.000;HRun=0;HaplotypeScore=0.9997;MQ=37.00;MQ0=0;MQRankSum=1.641;QD=35.27;ReadPosRankSum=1.459;1000gALT=T;AF1000g=0.01
```

I want to be able to replace the white space next to chr7 with a semi-colon. I then want to select lines in a certain range within the POS values, for example: 149601 to 149628 (the first three lines), so I can calculate the total value of AF100g in this range (the first three line being 0.24 in this example).

How can I do this?

Comment: What purpose does replacing the whitespace with semi colon serve ? You could look at `pandas`; it is very handy for manipulating structured data.

Comment: Hi fiixxxer. How can pandas help me with this type of file?

Comment: Not sure what the file format is, but it sure looks like Pandas would be the way to go.

Comment: first section is simple, you can use replace method but can you be more specific for second part of your question?

Comment: Sara, Thank you for the suggestion. For the second part, I want scan each line and keep track of the values of POS (line 1, POS = 149601) while summing the values of AF100g (line 1, this value is AF1000g=0.09). I want to stop scanning when I reach a difference of 30 or less. This is the difference between POS value of line 1, 149601 and line 3, 149628.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't quite understand what you mean by "a difference of 30 or less". Because line 1 (149601) and line 2 (149616) have a difference of 15 and it is here less than 30 already.

Now as to get the values you want (assumes you are iterating over the file and storing each line in a variable called `line`):

POS: I would suggest just replacing all spaces by exactly one space first and then using this space to split the string into parts (`line = re.sub(r" +", r" ", line)`). The second element will then be your POS value (`pos = int(line.split(" ")[1])`).

AF values: Just search for the key word using a regular expression: `float(re.match(r".*?AF1000g=(.*?)\s.*?", line).groups()[0])`

Keep a global variable that adds up your individual AF values in each loop step. Print the added up AF values when your desired condition is reached. Keep saving the previous POS value in a variable outside the loop and take the difference between the two pos values. Remember to use `abs()` if you want a positive value.